# WriteAllTextAsync method of System.IO.File class does not output text larger than 4kb

Tags: c#, .net

`WriteAllTextAsync` and `AppendAllTextAsync` methods are not able to write contents of a string if larger than 4kb in size. I am assuming this is some kind of buffer limitations but those methods do not support an overloaded method that accepts buffer size as a parameter. I am using .net framework 4.7.2

When `WriteAllText` or `AppendAllText` method of `File` class is used, the length of the output file is 254 kb with the entire text written but with `Async` versions of those methods only 4kb of output is written.

```
//Populate jsonString variable with a very large string
string jsonString = "placeholder for string content"; 

//Below code will output partial string till 4kb in length
File.AppendAllTextAsync("temp.json", jsonString);

//Below code outputs the entire content
File.AppendAllText("temp.json", jsonString);
```

Can someone provide an explanation for such behaviour and the solution to the problem

Comment: In short your doing it wrong you are not awaiting the the call, the 4k is the default buffer size used

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using Async call in bad way. When you are calling `File.AppendAllTextAsync` this way, new Task is executed. You have to wait for a result of this method by using a keyword `await`. If you are not awaiting, a program is ended before async call get completed and incomplete text is written.

So the right call is:

```
await File.AppendAllTextAsync("temp.json", jsonString);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying this in a console app, maybe the process has no time to write everything.
Can you try replacing

```
File.AppendAllTextAsync("temp.json", jsonString);
```

with

```
var task = File.AppendAllTextAsync("temp.json", jsonString);
task.Wait();
```

?

edit: the concern about .Wait() or .Result creating deadlocks, is valid in the context of an UI Thread. That is not the case here.

Comment: Don't use task.Wait()! It is blocking call and it has issues with deadlocks. Always use await. Right code is
`var task = File.AppendAllTextAsync("temp.json", jsonString);
await task;`

Comment: This was a suggestion to check this scenario. Using task.Wait() doesn't involve changing your method signature to be async and makes things easier for the one who asked the question.

Comment: In a Console program `.Wait()` is acceptable and before C# 7.1 it is the only option.

Comment: @CosminSontu The scenario is clearly bad. Not awaiting on async method is the cause of this behavior.